# Prevent JSOUP from unencoding attribute values

Tags: jsoup

I have code, somewhat, like this

```
String str = "<element data=\"some &lt;data&gt;\"> &gt;foo&lt; </element>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str, "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

But JSOUP unencodes **data's** value, producing something like this

```
<element value="some <data>">
  &gt;foo&lt;
</element>
```

How do I prevent JSOUP from unencoding attribute values?

Comment: What is your expected output? This is mine `<element data="some <data>">
`

Comment: I would expect it to be

`<element data="some &lt;data&gt;">`

Comment: There is apparently no way to do that : [look here](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) Why not changing it yourself with a regex?

Answer (score 1):

You're hitting a known issue of Jsoup (1.8.3 as of this writing).

See here for details: https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/55

The issue has been posted on December 27 2010... nearly 5 years before your question. I hope the upvotes on it will help raising attention to it.

**UPDATE**
Jsoup author has closed the issue as WON'T FIX.